# Why is child html object undefined/null

Tags: javascript, html, list, treeview

i can't figure out why the child object returns undefined in this code.

What the code does is create a tree of html objects it finds the child objects and the parent object of that element it finds an elements child objects, then adds them to a list, you can then (or meant to be able to) click on that list select the child you want and then that regenerates the tree with the child object you selected as the new current object.

an example

```
<div id="setone">
     <div id="setwo-one">
         <div id="setthree">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="settwo-two">
     </div>
</div>
```

the list will first select setone which becomes the current object you will see the child objects settwo-one and settwo-two you then click on them and then they become the current object except when you click on the childobject the **onclick > elementstart.children[i]** < becomes undefined and then can't find the tag or id of the object so the list breaks.

```
function treedialogupdate(elementstart)
{
if(elementstart != null)
{
    var treelog = document.getElementById("treedialog");

    var listset = treelog.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    listset.innerHTML = "";
    var beforeitem = treelog.getElementsByClassName("before")[0];
    var startitem = treelog.getElementsByClassName("start")[0];

    startitem.innerHTML =  "Current Object: " + elementstart.tagName + " " + elementstart.id;

    for(i = 0; i < elementstart.children.length; i++)
    {
        if(elementstart.children[i].tagName)
        {
            listset.innerHTML += "<li>" + elementstart.children[i].tagName + " " + elementstart.children[i].id + "</li>";

        }   
    }
    for(i = 0; i < childObjectList.length; i++)
    {
        listset.children[i].onclick =function(){ 
        treedialogupdate(elementstart.children[i]); };
    }

    if(elementstart.parentNode != null || elementstart.parentNode == "undefined")
    {
        beforeitem.innerHTML = "Parent Object: " +  elementstart.parentNode.tagName + " " elementstart.parentNode.id;
        beforeitem.onclick =function(){ treedialogupdate(elementstart.parentNode); };
    }
    else
    {
        beforeitem.innerHTML = "";
        beforeitem.onclick = "";
    }
}
}
```

(important section below)
I set the on click like this

```
 for(i = 0; i < elementstart.children.length; i++)
    {
        listset.children[i].onclick =function(){ 
            childrenOfElement = elementstart.children;
            console.log(childrenOfElement);
            console.log(childrenOfElement[i]);
            treedialogupdate(childrenOfElement[i]); 

        };
    }
```

This is what i get in the console

```
[section#header, section.fullwidth, section#footer, header: section#header, footer:      section#footer, item: function, namedItem: function]
page-functions.js:278 undefined
```

What your seeing is that the elementstart.children has children but when i go to use a specific element i.e childrenOfElement[i] it becomes undefined

Comment: What is `childObjectList`?

Comment: i removed that now the code section below has replaced it, it was just an array that got filled with the child objects. has no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I Couldn't delete the comment, I had put it on the wrong thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `i` is not what you think it is inside of your `onclick` handler. `i` belongs to the global scope. When the for loop that assigns the click handlers has completed, `i` will have a value equal to `elementstart.children.length` (we know this because the for loop loops *until* `i` is equal to  `elementstart.children.length`). When your `onclick` handler is called, `childrenOfElement[i]` is equivalent to `childrenOfElement[elementstart.children.length]` - which is, of course, `undefined`.

What you need to do is to create a new scope (which in JavaScript is a new function) for *each* iteration of your for loop. This scope will create a new variable which will contain the value of i *at that iteration*. You will then use this new variable as your index into the `childrenOfElement` array.

A sexy way of achieving this is with an immediately-invoked function expression (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
listset.children[i].onclick = (function(index) {
    return function () {
        childrenOfElement = elementstart.children;
        treedialogupdate(childrenOfElement[index]); 
    };
}(i));
```

Comment: You are a genius, spent some time on that never would of expected that to be the issue, and that link was very useful thank you. all working now

Answer (score 0):

(domElement).children is a javascript property that returns the array of children

```
var childrenOfElement = element.children
```

Comment: this casuses an error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: what is the type of elementStart that you are passing into your function?

Comment: at first it is the document.body, but you can click on an element and make that the current object so element start becomes event.target effectively the element that was clicked on

it can also become the child object that you want hence the onclick in the list object you see above so it would be whatever passes through the .children()

Comment: hmmm looks like the .children() method is like the jquery version of javascripts .children property, so please excuse my first response as it is wrong

Comment: ive updated my post might explain it a bit better i use .children and ive shown the console long

Comment: Try using .childNodes instead of .children

Comment: similar result except the console.log is cleaner

[section#header, section.fullwidth, section#footer, item: function]

undefined

Comment: This returns `undefined`.